# Can't containerise Python app with Docker

Tags: python, docker, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, containers

- I have a multi-directory Python Selenium app that I want to put into a container with Docker
- I don't have experience with this tech, so I tried making a Dockerfile this way
  Dockerfile:

  `FROM python:3.8 COPY ./* ./`

  `RUN pip install selenium pytest pytest-html`

  `CMD python /tests/form_page/test_form_page.py`
- I want this Python app run from a container
- I also uderstand that I need to add a venv (probably) and a Chrome driver for this app to work, but I don't know how to do this

Could you please help me out on this one?

PS if this would help here's the source code https://github.com/anatolyRozhkov/RozhkovPetProject.git

Comment: The standard Python image certainly does not include a GUI, let alone then Chrome or Firefox. You'll need to set up quite a bit of software by hand, or find a better image to start from. Look for a "headless browser" image perhaps; adding Python and Selenium to that should be a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you have install Google Chrome browser and Chrome driver inside your `Dockerfile`. Then build the docker image in your container and run your docker images using the command `docker run <image_name>:latest`

```
FROM python:3.8

# install google chrome
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable

# install chromedriver
RUN apt-get install -yqq unzip
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# set display port to avoid crash
ENV DISPLAY=:99

RUN pip install selenium
RUN pip install pytest

WORKDIR /app -#python file that u want to run
COPY . /app

CMD ["python", "/tests/form_page/test_form_page.py"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this should help! Could you please explain what is 
_WORKDIR /app -#python file that u want to run_? Do I still need to specify the path to the python file I want to run in the CMD?

Comment: According to this documentation https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir , The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile. If the WORKDIR doesn’t exist, it will be created even if it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction. I believe that i work as a working directory so that it can perform the specific instructions.  you should run the docker image using the command "docker run <image_name>. I believe u can retrieve the image name  using the command "docker images"

Comment: Feel free to ask here again if you encountered any problems . I would be willing to help you :D